# Zone.assertZonePatched is not a function

Tags: angular, zonejs

I am getting the error message:

Unhandled Promise rejection: Zone.assertZonePatched is not a function

Although I am importing zonejs correctly in index.html:

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.17/dist/zone.js"></script>
```

Here is the code:

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/zZYOcgxcRINx23JhuxOk?p=preview

What is wrong here?

Comment: Where and how can I find error in your plunker? Its working !

Comment: It should be stuck showing the message: "loading...". If I open up my dev tools in chrome I see the above described issue.

Comment: Oh means in your real app you have issue not in plunker?

Comment: i am getting the same error with the new RC7

Comment: @JKing In real app or in plunker?

Comment: both, I see the error in the linked plunker from this post and in my own real app

Comment: @JKing Would you share plunker with RC7? check my answer below as well.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- ***RC7***

Update ***zone.js*** pakage by  ***zone.js@0.6.21***

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.21/dist/zone.js"></script>
```

---

- ***Angular2.0 release***

Update ***zone.js*** package by ***zone.js@0.6.23***,

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.23?main=browser"></script>
```

Comment: you are right.  I had updated my packages.json file but I forgot to run my gulp task that copies the new version into my src directory.  Once I did that it all works again.

Comment: here is the change log that outlines the TWO peer dependency changes:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
core: zone.js@0.6.21
core: rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12

Comment: confirmed, this was updated in the official tutorial plunker as well: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-5/ts/plnkr.html

Comment: @BrianVanderPlaats. your plunker is hard to understand for anyone as it has so many files. why not to use less files version (RC7 plunker)???  Here it is : http://plnkr.co/edit/NrUanszzdQDGzi1tpuuM?p=preview

Comment: @micronyks that plunker was from the Routing Tutorial on the Angular.io site.  Thanks for posting a barebones template, looks good.

Comment: Welcome. :) ...Yes that I know. But people should start from basics so just referenced it here in case if anybody is willing to go with RC7.

Answer (score 1):

Update package.json file

"zone.js": "0.6.25"

inside dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Also, after updating to 0.6.23, I received the following error:

Unhandled promise rejection Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.

Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)

After loading my **core-js/client/shim.min.js** BEFORE zone.js, my app was working again.